How do Object.getOwnPropertySymbols and Reflect.ownKeys handle Symbols in Javascript?
No two Symbols are equal in JavaScript. So Symbol('foo') == Symbol('foo') is false. If I have an object with a Symbol property I cannot access that property if I hadn't already saved that symbol in a variable.
obj = {[Symbol('foo')]: 'bar'};
console.log(obj[Symbol('foo')]); // undefined

But using Object.getOwnPropertySymbols and Reflect.ownKeys I can retrieve Symbol property:
console.log(obj[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)[0]]); // bar
console.log(obj[Reflect.ownKeys(obj)[0]]); // bar

How these two static methods can access the same Symbol. Do they have access to internal structure of Symbol repository?

"Do they have access to internal structure of Symbol repository?" Yes. The other questions ask about implementation details and can be different in each implementation.

You have saved that symbol in a variable, which in the form of the first of key of obj.

Both routines (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols and Reflect.ownKeys) generate a list that you can iterate through. Calling the respective item (by using [propName]) of that list gives you access to that stored symbol reference. It doesn't generate a new one like calling Symbol('foo') does. They both return a list of the respective properties present on that object you passed as argument.
